# Not getting right answer for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

So I was trying to calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}dx$$using the Residue theorem. To solve this one, I chose the semi-circular contour. The function has poles at $\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}i}{2}$. To find the order of the poles, I have to find the smallest $n$ such that $$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}z^nf(z)$$exists ($z_0$ is the pole). Then $n$ would be the order of the pole. First I tried $n=1$ and I got $$\lim_{z\rightarrow\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}i}{2}}\frac{x}{1+x+x^2}=\lim_{z\rightarrow\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}i}{2}}\frac{1}{1+2x}=\frac{1}{1+2\left(\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{\mp\sqrt{3}i}$$Right at this point I found out I was doing something wrong. The result of the $n$-th order pole test is the same as the residues of the poles. When I add them together I get zero, but $\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}$ never touches the $x$-axis. What is wrong here?

Comment: The semicircular contour only contains one of the poles.

Comment: And your limit expression is wrong. It should be $x-(-1+\sqrt{3}i)/2$ on the numerator. Otherwise, the basic condition for the use of L'Hopital is unjustified. You should also get used to determining orders by inspection. This polynomial has two distinct roots, is a quadratic, looking at the factorisation it should be clear that the order is one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not add, because you only have one pole which is encircled by your half circle. For example, if you choose a circle on the upper half plane, it encircles the $(-1 + \sqrt{3} i)/2$ pole which contributes $2 \pi i$ times the residue $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3} i}$ so the integral will equate the opposite of this contribution, yielding a value

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x+x^2}dx = \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Ohhhh I see. I forgot about the fact that poles must be in the contour. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you are doing wrong is that, when you are aiming at determining the order of a pole at $z_0$, what you should determine is the only $n\in\Bbb N$ such that$$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z\color{red}{-z_0})^nf(z)\ne0.$$In your case, you have$$\lim_{z\to-1/2\pm i\sqrt{3}/2}\frac{z-\left(-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)}{z^2+z+1}=\mp\frac i{\sqrt3}\ne0.$$Besides, among the points $-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2i$, the only one in the region bounded by the contour of your choice is $-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$. So, the other pole doesn't matter.

Comment: Ohhhh I see. I forgot about the fact that poles must be in the contour. Thanks for your answer!